# How to use tabs with canvas

Tags: tkinter, tabs, tkinter-canvas

i am designing a GUI where i want different images to be displayed in multiple tabs and i am using canvas for the same. however when i open an image in one tab, it opens but when an image is opened in another tab , the image that was opened in the previous tab gets cleared.

```
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Text-Editor')
    root.resizable(width=True, height=True)
    root.geometry("1400x660")
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    
    my_frame = Frame(root)
    my_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
    my_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    my_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=6)
    my_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    
    left_frame = Frame(my_frame)
    left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
    left_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    left_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    right_frame = Frame(my_frame)
    right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nswe")
    right_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    right_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    
    tabcontrol = ttk.Notebook(right_frame)
    tabcontrol.grid(row = 0 , column = 0 , sticky = "nswe")
    
    my_menu = Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=my_menu)
    
    scrollbar_object = Scrollbar(left_frame)
    scrollbar_object2 = Scrollbar(right_frame)
    scrollbar_object.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
    scrollbar_object2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
    def permap_img():
        global img
        per_map(gpath)
        xscrollbar = Scrollbar(right_frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        xscrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E + W)
        yscrollbar = Scrollbar(right_frame)
        yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N + S)
        canvas_1 = Canvas(right_frame, bd=0, xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set, yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
        canvas_1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N + S + E + W)
        file = "map.png"
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(file))
        canvas_1.create_image(0 , 0 ,image=img, anchor=CENTER)
        canvas_1.config(scrollregion=canvas_1.bbox(ALL))
        xscrollbar.config(command=canvas_1.xview)
        yscrollbar.config(command=canvas_1.yview)
        tabcontrol.add(canvas_1)
    
    def nvd_img():
        global img
        nvdmap(gpath)
        xscrollbar = Scrollbar(right_frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        xscrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E + W)
        yscrollbar = Scrollbar(right_frame)
        yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N + S)
        canvas_2 = Canvas(right_frame, xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set, yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
        canvas_2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N + S + E + W)
        file = "nvd_map.png"
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(file))
        canvas_2.create_image(0, 0, image=img, anchor="center")
        canvas_2.config(scrollregion=canvas_2.bbox(ALL))
        xscrollbar.config(command=canvas_2.xview)
        yscrollbar.config(command=canvas_2.yview)
        tabcontrol.add(canvas_2)
visual_menu = Menu(my_menu , tearoff = False)
my_menu.add_cascade(label = "Visualize", menu = visual_menu)
permissions_menu.add_command(label = "Normal Vs Dangerous", command = nvd_img)
permissions_menu.add_command(label = "Permission Categories" , command = permap_img)
```

This is the code that i have tried so far . Could anyone help me with why this is happening? also the scrollbar works in one tab and when i open a new image in another tab it doesnt work

Comment: please reduce your code to [mre]

Comment: You seem to be sharing the variable `img` between the two tabs. When the second tab is created, the first image will be over written and disappear from the first tab. Keep the PhotoImage objects inside a seperate global variable for each.

Comment: And what about the scrollbar?it's giving the same problem